# Why prefer defaults() over Javascript prototyping?

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, default-value, prototyping

With Underscore.js, we can use [`defaults()`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) to apply default values to an object.

```
var defaultProperties = { flavor : "vanilla", sprinkles : "lots" };
var iceCream = {flavor : "chocolate"};
_.defaults(iceCream, defaultProperties);
```

But in Javascript, default values could be realized by using prototypes, too.

```
var defaultProperties = { flavor : "vanilla", sprinkles : "lots" };
var iceCream = Object.create(defaultProperties);
iceCream.flavor = "chocolate";
```

What is the advantage and use case of Underscore.js' `defaults()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Mostly availability.

   `Object.create()` is available in [ES5-compatible browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/), while `_.defaults()` will function in older, ES3-based browsers (IE8, IE7, etc.).
2. Also for objects you didn't `create()`.

   If the object already exists, you can't count on being able to alter its `[[Prototype]]` after-the-fact to establish the desires inheritance.

   It's possible in some browsers, but [not standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).
3. It might make things easier with more than 1 `defaults` object.

   ```
   _.defaults(options, config, defaults);
   ```

   This is possible with prototype chains, but you have to establish one.

   ```
   var defaults = { /* ... */ };

   var config = Object.create(defaults);
   config.mixed = true;
   ```

   ```
   var iceCream = Object.create(config);
   iceCream.flavor = 'chocolate';
   ```

But, in general, they serve very similar purposes. They just do so from different perspectives:

- `_.default()` iterates to find and set what's missing.
- `Object.create()` uses prototype chains to inherit what's missing.

So, which to use is largely up to you and your personal preferences.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing come to my mind reading your last paragraph. Objects filled by `defaults()` might be a tick faster since accessing their properties later on doesn't require to traverse the prototype chain.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference except that using Underscore's defaults function saves you from writing extra code for validating and assigning a set of properties to the desired object. By abstracting that into a single function your code would look a bit more meaningful and neat. Which makes it a handy utility function.

Here is the source of Underscore's defaults function

```
// Fill in a given object with default properties.
  _.defaults = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
      if (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
          if (obj[prop] === void 0) obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };
```

It takes the object and set of values as parameter, loops through the set of propeties and if the property doesn't already exist in that object, assign it to it. Source: [UnderscoreJS code on Github](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js)